# Phoenix/Brunch not execute js imported file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, phoenix-framework, brunch

1 - Im using Phoenix framework and brunch, by now my problem is that just `app.js` is executed, thats sucks, now i have one page `search` and want execute specific js in this file like `search.js` and dont know how to do.

I know that brunch put everything as module as said in `brunch-config.js`: 

`// However, those files will only be executed if
// explicitly imported. The only exception are files
// in vendor, which are never wrapped in imports and
// therefore are always executed.`

And i try create an module `search-2.js` and import this in `search.js` like:

`import socket from "./search-2"`

but the file never execute, i experiment put this file in `app.js` and the javascript is executed. What is wrong ? What is the condition/config to file be executed instead just be an class/module.

2 - If have an good practice to add specific page js in this case.

3 - Maybe and silly doubt: Why this default configuration ? They assume that all apps that gonna be made are SPA ?

Thanks a lot by now, im stuck here.